# Example of finite field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I have this factorization: $y^3+2x^3=(y+x\sqrt[3]{2})(y+\omega x\sqrt[3]{2})(y+\omega^2 x\sqrt[3]{2})$

Does exist an algebraic field extension as:  $\mathbb{Q}[\omega ,\sqrt[3]{2}]$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ ,  where: $\omega=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$  and $x,y\in{\mathbb{Q}}$ ?

Can be this its integral basis: $\{1,\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[3]{4},\omega,\omega\sqrt[3]{2}\}$ ?

And what would be its minimal polynomial?

Thanks

Comment: We have $\omega^2-\omega+1=0.$ Consider $p(x)=(x^2-x+1)(x^3-2).$

Comment: Have you tried to compute the discriminant of those 6 elements? If it is square-free it is an integral basis (but not conversely).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Then, i understand this basis is correct, dont you?

Comment: Hi daruma. Its degree is five, dont you? : 5 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask two distinct types of questions:

1) I don't understand your algebraic question: when adding algebraic elements to an algebraic number field, you obtain an algebraic number field (this must be somewhere in your course). Here you have more precise information : since $[\mathbf Q(\omega):\mathbf Q]=2$ and $[\mathbf Q(\sqrt [3] 2):\mathbf Q]=3$, you get $[\mathbf Q(\omega,\sqrt [3] 2):\mathbf Q]=6$. The "basis" that you give is incorrect since it has only 5 elements. Here, since the two basic fields are linearly disjoint over $\mathbf Q$, you have only to multiply between them the elements of two respective bases to get the basis {$1,\omega, \sqrt [3] 2, \sqrt [3] 4, \omega \sqrt [3] 2, \omega \sqrt [3] 4$} of $K = \mathbf Q(\omega,\sqrt [3] 2)$.

2) Your arithmetic question is whether the basis above, which consists of algebraic integers, is an integral basis of $O_K$, the ring of integers of $K$. The usual tool in the determination of integral bases is the discriminant, but it gives a necessary and sufficient conditions iff disc($O_K$) itself is known. Otherwise, you have only sufficient criteria such as the square free condition evoked by @daruma. In the particular case here, if you don't like computing discriminants, you can use some general criteria relative to cyclotomic fields and pure cubic fields. Start from the following general theorem : *Let $k_1, k_2$ be two number fields of respective degrees $n_1, n_2$ over $\mathbf Q$, and respective rings of integers $O_1, O_2$. Denote by $K$ the compositum of $k_1$and $k_2$, and $D=gcd(disc(O_1), disc (O_2))$. If $[K:\mathbf Q]=n_1n_2$, then $O_K \subset D^{-1}O_1O_2$. If moreover $D=1$, then $O_K=O_1O_2$* (see D. Marcus, "Number Fields", chap.2, thm.12). Apply this to $k_1=\mathbf Q(\omega)$ and $k_2=\mathbf Q(\sqrt [3] 2)$. For the cyclotomic field $k_1$, it is classically known that an integral basis of $O_1$ is {$1, \omega$}. As for pure cubic fields $k_2=\mathbf Q(\sqrt [3] m)$, where $m$ is a cubic free integer, explicit integral bases are given at the end of chap.2 of *op.cit.* according to congruences of $m$ (mod 9). In your case here, an integral basis of $O_2$ is {$1,\sqrt [3] 2, \sqrt [3] 4$}. So, after the theorem above, the answer to your question is YES.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for your time and sorry for my few studies on the subject. I will study from what you say. It is very interesting. Sincerely